# bootstrap accordion panel-heading cursor anomaly when expanding panel

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, cursor, accordion

I have a rather strange issue with the panel-header in the bootstrap accordion.
When I click on the anchor tag `<a>` in the header the panel-body expands, collapses as expected.  The mouse cursor, which I have not moved stays as a pointer (hand) through the whole process of collapsing/expanding.

However, if I click outside the anchor tag on the page and then I go back and click the anchor tag in the panel-heading again, now the mouse cursor will change to default (arrow) when I click and stay an arrow until I move the move slightly within the anchor tag at which time it then goes back to the pointer.

If close the tab or restart the browser (IE) and go back to the page or even just refresh the page and move immediately to the anchor tag and click, everything works fine until I click elsewhere on the page and then the anomaly shows up and persists until the browser/tab is closed and re-opened or the page is refreshed.

I thought this was something in my code but even the example Bootstrap Accordion code suffers from this behavior.
See the Accordion section at the bottom of the [Bootstrap Collapse](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_collapse.asp)
 page.

Fiddle me [here](https://jsfiddle.net/Fiddleage/bbsgy7z7/)...`to reproduce in my fiddle`:

1. Click any of the Collapsible Groups and note how the cursor does not change from the pointer (hand)
2. Click anywhere somewhere on the page so that the anchor tag loses focusses (dotted-box disappears)
3. Go back to the anchor tag and notice how when the cursor hovers it changes back to the pointer (hand) as expected) BUT if you now click you'll notice that every time it toggles the body the cursor changes to default (arrow) and stays that way if you don't move it...if you do move the cursor (but still within the anchor tag region) it then does return back to a hand.

At a bit of a loss here and any help would be greatly appreciated as I'm running out of hair.

Thanks.

Comment: Can't duplicate. Which browser?

Comment: IE 11 (11.0.9600.18282).